# How to efficiently join two dataframes on multiple OR keys?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have two dataframes in scala dataframeA (Large) and dataframeB (Smaller)
I need to fetch all rows of dataframeA (with dataframeB columns) which match any of the 3 different join keys.

Something of this sort,

```
    Val joinedDF = dataframeA.join($"cid_a" === $"cid_b" || $"tax_id_a" === $"tax_id_b" || $"group_id_a" === $"group_id_b", "left")
```

This is working but taking roughly 5 times the time what it took before this join was introduced.
What better way to implement such join in spark scala?

Comment: Smaller is what size? Unclear how OR is efficiently handled, may be better to have multiple queries

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the smaller `DataFrame` is guaranteed to stay relatively constant across multiple runs and can be fitted entirely on one executor then you could broadcast join:

```scala
dfa.join(
  right = broadcast(dfb),
  joinExprs = $"cid_a" === $"cid_b" || $"tax_id_a" === $"tax_id_b" || $"group_id_a" === $"group_id_b",
  joinType = "left")
```

See [performance tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#join-strategy-hints-for-sql-queries).

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things and the one that worked eventually is joining one key at a time and then doing a union on the 3 results

For eg:

```
val joinedDF1 = dataframeA.join(dataframeB,$"cid_a" === $"cid_b","inner")
val joinedDF2 = dataframeA.join(dataframeB,$"tax_id_a" === $"tax_id_b","inner")
val joinedDF3 = dataframeA.join(dataframeB,$"group_id_a" === $"group_id_b", "inner")

val finalDFJoined = joinedDF1.union(joinedDF2).union(joinedDF3)
```

Comment: can this work with AND case but not OR case?